# PostMessage tutorial

Tags: windows, visual-c++, messaging

I am looking for some tutorial regarding the PostMessage functionality in Windows SDK. I have been googling a while but no luck. Is there a site which elaborates on this operation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) explains the operation of the message queueing system, including things like the difference between PostMessage and SendMessage.

For some more interesting reading, you should probably look at [this](http://www.flounder.com/messages.htm). It concentrates on user-defined messages, but has some interesting insights which could prevent you getting into bad messaging habits.

Answer (score 0):

Press Help and search for PostMessage in Visual C++ (or whatever tools you use).
It has quite a lengthy explanation